# How to increase the quality of product images JPG Magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2, css, product-images, magento2.3.4

I'm using Magento 2.3.4. my uploaded product images quantity is very low because of compression. My product images size in 30 to 40 kbs, can someone help me increase images quantity?

Comment: you mean the image quality?

Comment: yes, sorry misspelled